# How to add a custom last row within a table using jspdf-Autotable

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to build a small app with **jspdf** and **jspdf-Autotable** but I don't find how to create a custom last row with another variable value in an existing table.

What I just have done so far is this:

```
  doc.autoTable({ 
    body: concepts,
    columns: [{ header: 'Concept', dataKey: 'name' }, { header: 'Amount', dataKey: 'amount' }],
    didDrawPage: function (data) {
        let rows = data.table.body;
        rows.push({ 
          content: 'Total = ' + total,
          colSpan: 2
        });
        if (data.row.index === rows.length - 1) { doc.setFillColor(239, 154, 154); }
    }
  });
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm getting confused on how to face this problem. `total` comes with a number value but I want to print it in one custom last row alone but within the table, kind like an Excel rule would do.

Any suggestion would be helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add your custom data before processing the elements. Use `...` to destructure the data and merge with the new row.

```js
function generate() {
  var doc = new jsPDF();

  var data = [
    {name: "Bar", amount: 1200}, 
    {name: "Zap", amount: 200}, 
    {name: "Foo", amount: 320}];
    
  var total = data.reduce((sum, el) => sum + el.amount, 0);

  var body = [...data.map(el => [el.name, el.amount]), 
    [{content: `Total = ${total}`, colSpan: 2, 
      styles: { fillColor: [239, 154, 154] }
    }]]

  doc.autoTable({
    head: [['Concept', 'Amount']],
    body: body
  });

  doc.save("table.pdf");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.5.3/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@3.4.1/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<button onclick="generate()">Generate PDF</button>
```